# Подключение скрипта в <head> в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, telegram, typescript

Разрабатываю Mini App для Телеграмма на React и TypeScript в VSCode.
Как и написано в документации, для связи Телеграмма с Mini App размещаю ссылку на скрипт в  index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
```

По идеe, после этого должен стать доступен объект window.Telegram.WebApp, однако при присвоении его переменной, TS выдаёт ошибку "Property 'Telegram' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)"

```
 const tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: где именно ты пишешь `const tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;`?

Comment: можно подключить типы для этой библиотеки, например такие: https://github.com/prKassad/telegram-webapps-types

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте этот код над вашим компонентом

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        Telegram: any;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]